# How moon north/south nodes can be calculated

Tags: the-moon

If the planetary geocentric position of the moon is known (say, longitude 
"254°31'35"") is it possible to calculate such position for north/south (ascending/descending) moon nodes? Or what else needs to be known?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no.

The lunar nodes vary in a roughly uniform fashion, taking about 18 years to vary by 360 degrees. The longitude of the moon at a given time is not part of the calculation.

The details are complex, since they involve the dynamics of a three body system. Nasa has a system called "SPICE" that lets you calculate positions of orbiting bodies. There is [a web interface to spice](http://wgc.jpl.nasa.gov:8080/webgeocalc/#NewCalculation) available. And the details of using this to calculate lunar nodes is described on the [space exploration stack exchange](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/18718/calculating-positions-of-moons-ascending-and-descending-nodes-from-ephemeris-fi)

A rough calculation can be done by approximating by a linear function of time.